# How to prevent application installation on Windows programatically?

Tags: windows, installation, driver, block

Right now, I have one solution for this:

- I use a driver to monitor any process about to execute. When the driver detect that, it will send information of the process (ex: *.exe) to a user-mode app.
- The app will then check for "Product name" info of that *.exe file. If the "Product name" is  one of common software installers, like: InstallShield, WiX..., user-mode app will call driver to block it.

My question is: Is there any better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Ultimately an installer is just something that puts a bunch of stuff on the machine.  While it's best practice to use a proper installer platform (MSI, InstallShield, etc.) there is no requirement to do so.  Granted not a lot of stuff strays outside of the norm, but your approach will not be 100%.

Comment: I know my solution is not perfect for those cases which companies build installer by themselves. That's why I wait for a better solution.